# Feeding a list within a column to cut2

Tags: r, list

I have data as follows, which has lists in the `strata` column:

```
library(data.table)
library(Hmisc)
dat <- structure(list(values = c(25, 11, 21, 15), strata = list(c(10, 20, 30, 40), c(10, 20, 30), c(10, 20), c(10, 30))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

   values      strata
1:     25 10,20,30,40
2:     31    10,20,30
3:     45       10,20
4:     62       10,30
```

I would like to use the list in the `strata` column as the cut-off values for `cut2`. I tried:

```
dat <- setDT(dat)[, cat:= cut2(values, strata, oneval=FALSE)]
```

But that gives:

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

How should I handle this?

Desired output:

```
   values      strata  cat
1:     25 10,20,30,40  [20,30)
2:     11    10,20,30  [10,20)
3:     21       10,20  [20,)
4:     15       10,30  [10,30)
```

Comment: Is that `Hmisc::cut2`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the libraries in.. One second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to call `cut2` iteratively, once for each pair of `values` and `strata`, you can use `mapply`:

```r
setDT(dat)
dat[, cat := mapply(Hmisc::cut2, values, strata)]
dat
#    values      strata     cat
#     <num>      <list>  <fctr>
# 1:     25 10,20,30,40 [20,30)
# 2:     11    10,20,30 [10,20)
# 3:     21       10,20 [20,21]
# 4:     15       10,30 [10,30]
```

I can't replicate the desired `[20,)`, perhaps I'm missing something in the function itself. Either way, I think this is the *mechanism* you need.