# Fastest way to check to which bracket a value belongs for large data

Tags: r, data.table, hmisc

The data below has lists in the `strata` column. I would like to use the list in the `strata` column as the cut-off values. The solution provided below comes from [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884047/8071608).

The problem is that I am using quite a large data-set. As a result I was wondering whether there are faster ways to achieve the same thing.

```
# DATA

library(data.table)
library(Hmisc)
dat <- structure(list(values = c(25, 11, 21, 15), strata = list(c(10, 20, 30, 40), c(10, 20, 30), c(10, 20), c(10, 30))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

#    values      strata
# 1:     25 10,20,30,40
# 2:     11    10,20,30
# 3:     21       10,20
# 4:     15       10,30

# CURRENT SOLUTION

setDT(dat)
dat[, cat := mapply(cut, values, strata, oneval=FALSE)]
dat
#    values      strata     cat
#     <num>      <list>  <fctr>
# 1:     25 10,20,30,40 [20,30)
# 2:     11    10,20,30 [10,20)
# 3:     21       10,20 <NA>
# 4:     15       10,30 [10,30]
```

## EDIT:

Result for the actual data:

```
# 2 minutes
dat[, cat := mapply(cut2, values, strata, oneval=FALSE)]

# 51 seconds
dat[, cat := mapply(cut, values, strata, oneval=FALSE)]

# 21 seconds
solution by arau

# 8 seconds
solution by Uwe

# 44 seconds to load, 0.2 seconds to compute
Solution by onyambu
```

Comment: Why not use `cut`? why use `cut2`? is it faster?

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for your comment. Could you explain why `cut` would be faster?

Comment: I am not sure which is faster, just curious why use a function from a different package while there is a function that does exactly the same thing in base R. if its for convenience/speed I would understand. But in your case I dont understand.

Comment: Also I see `cut2` having alot of overheads than `cut` try using `cut`

Comment: @onyambu, just checked. `cut` is already more than twice as fast. I will adapt the question.

Comment: Does that solve the problem or still it takes too long?

Comment: @onyambu It is still too long, so I edited the question with your suggestion :)

Comment: Try using rcpp to run your code.

Comment: Did you find a faster way?

Comment: Are `strata` always sorted?

Comment: Have you tried `findInterval()`? It's the workhorse behind `cut` and doesn't e.g. waste time turning output into a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to speed up things consider using Rcpp. (Note in this case I just wrote a purely c++ function which I read into R using Rcpp)

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "std::vector<std::string> interval(std::vector<int> &x,
                                     std::vector<std::vector<int>> &y){
    std::vector<std::string> z;
    z.reserve(x.size());
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), std::back_inserter(z), 
      [&](int a, std::vector<int> b) {
        auto it = std::find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [=](int w) {return a < w;});
        return it==b.begin() | it == b.end()? \"NA\":
              '[' + std::to_string(*(it-1)) + ',' + std::to_string(*it) + ')';
    });
    return z;
  }"
)

dat[, cat:=interval(values, strata)]
dat
  values      strata     cat
1:     25 10,20,30,40 [20,30)
2:     11    10,20,30 [10,20)
3:     21       10,20      NA
4:     15       10,30 [10,30)
```

speed comparison:

Note that for a small dataset:

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(OP_solution=dat[, cat := mapply(cut, values, strata, oneval=FALSE)], Rcpp=dat[, cat:=interval(values, strata)], Arau_solution = arau(dat))
Unit: microseconds
          expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
   OP_solution  843.000  878.2010  917.592  898.7510  931.1515   1564.9   100
          Rcpp  301.301  317.8515  339.930  326.7015  337.2010   1425.4   100
 Arau_solution 3917.300 4059.9010 7295.939 4214.5005 4381.9510 305882.8   100
```

and for big data:

```
dat<-do.call(rbind, replicate(1000, dat, simplify = F))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(OP_solution=dat[, cat := mapply(cut, values, strata, oneval=FALSE)], Rcpp=dat[, cat:=interval(values, strata)], Arau_solution = long_merge(dat))
Unit: milliseconds
          expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
   OP_solution 418.765001 438.206901 463.993935 454.652851 472.974501 782.981200   100
          Rcpp   1.547401   1.685352   1.895221   1.759301   1.917451   5.185102   100
 Arau_solution 227.064100 239.994302 260.242264 251.936452 264.225652 605.567101   100
```

Note that Rcpp outperforms the rest. Arun solution is 200 times slower than the Rcpp solution

--- where:

```
arau <- function(dat){
  dat[, tmp_id := .I]  # create a temporary identifier for each value row
  
  # NB: can remove the sort call if the strata are already ordered increasing
  dat_long = dat[, .(values, lb = sort(unlist(strata))), by = tmp_id]
  dat_long[, ub := shift(lb, -1), by = tmp_id]
  dat_long = dat_long[!is.na(ub)]
  
  dat_result = merge(
    dat, dat_long[lb <= values & values < ub, -'values'], by = 'tmp_id', all.x = T)
  dat_result[!is.na(lb) & !is.na(ub), cat := paste0('[', lb, ', ', ub, ')')]
  dat_result[, .(values, strata, cat)]
}
```

## EDIT

It is flawed when @uwe claims that the RCPP code provided is slow yet they only compare the last part of their code to the Rcpp code. Why not compare their whole code? Here is the microbenchmark of the two codes--providing the times. Not the graphs.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "std::vector<std::string> interval(std::vector<int> &x,
                                     std::vector<std::vector<int>> &y){
    std::vector<std::string> z;
    z.reserve(x.size());
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), std::back_inserter(z), 
      [&](int a, std::vector<int> b) {
        auto it = std::find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [=](int w) {return a < w;});
        return it==b.begin() | it == b.end()? \"NA\":
              '[' + std::to_string(*(it-1)) + ',' + std::to_string(*it) + ')';
    });
    return z;
  }"
)


Rcpp_fun <- function(dat1){
  dat <- copy(dat1)
  dat[, cat:=interval(values, strata)][]
}

uwe <- function(dat1){
  dat <- copy(dat1)
  setDT(dat)[, strata_id := .I]
  lut <- dat[, .(lo = head(strata[[1]], -1L), 
                 hi = tail(strata[[1]], -1L)), by = strata_id][
                   , cat := sprintf("[%i,%i)", lo, hi)][]
  
  
  dat[lut, on = .(strata_id, values >= lo, values < hi), cat := i.cat]
  dat[, strata_id:=NULL][]
}

dat1 <- structure(list(values = c(25, 11, 21, 15), strata = list(c(10, 20, 30, 40), c(10, 20, 30), c(10, 20), c(10, 30))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                        -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
dat1<- rbindlist(replicate(1e5, dat1, simplify = FALSE))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Rcpp_fun(dat1), uwe(dat1))
```

Results?

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Rcpp_fun(dat1), uwe(dat1))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
 Rcpp_fun(dat1)  157.5878  173.5254  216.1008  189.931  227.0475   641.286   100
      uwe(dat1) 5905.8138 6332.8186 7096.8007 6689.716 7270.8831 15575.635   100
```

Clearly the Results show that Rcpp is ATLEAST 30X faster than @uwe code. Why would someone claim Their code is faster yet the graphs provided shows otherwise? Note that the code above takes roughly 5 minutes to do the benchmark.

Unless shown otherwise, the Rcpp code provided is the fastest of the 3 solutions provided.

Comment: Please, can you double check the C++ code? For values smaller than the smallest cut-off value it returns an artificial category instead of `NA`. In particular, for negative `values` it returns `[0,10)`, e.g. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe I did not consider that scenario. You can include that in the if else statement

Comment: @onyambu Thank you for this great addition. Do you know why initialising the function takes over 40 seconds to load? It is not a huge deal, but I was curious if this was normal and if so, what the reason is.

Comment: @Tom, that is compilation. Compilation time has nothing to do with run time. Any c++ code must be compiled including a simple `Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")`. Try it out and see how long it takes

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution in base `data.table` that I think might be faster on your larger dataset (although it's hard to tell given the small size of the example).

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- structure(list(values = c(25, 11, 21, 15), strata = list(c(10, 20, 30, 40), c(10, 20, 30), c(10, 20), c(10, 30))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

setDT(dat)
```

The idea is that we can vectorize the bucketing by breaking the provided strata into columns for the lower bound (`lb`) and upper bound (`ub`), then comparing using simple `<`/`<=` in `data.table`'s `i` clause.

```r
dat[, tmp_id := .I]  # create a temporary identifier for each value row

# NB: can remove the sort call if the strata are already ordered increasing
dat_long = dat[, .(values, lb = sort(unlist(strata))), by = tmp_id]
dat_long[, ub := shift(lb, -1), by = tmp_id]
dat_long = dat_long[!is.na(ub)]

dat_result = merge(
  dat, dat_long[lb <= values & values < ub, -'values'], by = 'tmp_id', all.x = T)
```

The hard part is done by this point...

```r
dat_result
#     tmp_id values      strata lb ub
#  1:      1     25 10,20,30,40 20 30
#  2:      2     11    10,20,30 10 20
#  3:      3     21       10,20 NA NA
#  4:      4     15       10,30 10 30
```

...so now we can just clean up.

```r
dat_result[!is.na(lb) & !is.na(ub), cat := paste0('[', lb, ', ', ub, ')')]
dat_result = dat_result[, .(values, strata, cat)]

dat_result
#      values      strata      cat
#   1:     25 10,20,30,40 [20, 30)
#   2:     11    10,20,30 [10, 20)
#   3:     21       10,20     <NA>
#   4:     15       10,30 [10, 30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which uses a *non-equi join* with a *lookup table* of the the upper and lower bounds of each category. Surprisingly, it turned out to be faster for larger problem sizes than [onyambu's Rcpp approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72648486/3817004) according to my benchmark. It does not require to write C++ code.

The OP has mentioned that he is using quite a large data-set. Assuming that there is only a limited number of different strata types, i.e., lists of different cut-off values, the strata types and cut-off values can be collected in a separate table. (My gut feeling is that the strata are given values anyway which have been assigned to each row of observed values using some undisclosed logic.)

The lookup table can be derived from posted dataset by

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
setDT(dat)[, strata_id := .I]
lut <- dat[, .(lo = head(strata[[1]], -1L), 
               hi = tail(strata[[1]], -1L)), by = strata_id][
                 , cat := sprintf("[%i,%i)", lo, hi)][]
lut
```

> ```
>    strata_id    lo    hi     cat
>        <int> <num> <num>  <char>
> 1:         1    10    20 [10,20)
> 2:         1    20    30 [20,30)
> 3:         1    30    40 [30,40)
> 4:         2    10    20 [10,20)
> 5:         2    20    30 [20,30)
> 6:         3    10    20 [10,20)
> 7:         4    10    30 [10,30)
> ```

Now, `cat` can be appended to `dat` by

```
dat[lut, on = .(strata_id, values >= lo, values < hi), cat := i.cat]
dat
```

> ```
>    values      strata strata_id     cat
>     <num>      <list>     <int>  <char>
> 1:     25 10,20,30,40         1 [20,30)
> 2:     11    10,20,30         2 [10,20)
> 3:     21       10,20         3    <NA>
> 4:     15       10,30         4 [10,30)
> ```

#### Benchmark

The benchmark compares the three approaches

- [arau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644357/3817004)
- [rcpp by onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72648486/3817004)
- lut: using a *non-equi join* with a lookup table

for different problem sizes

- 100, 1000, 10k, and 100k rows,
- 4 or 10 different strata types
- with 3 or 10 categories in each strata type

To deal with the different problem sizes, makeshift test data is created for each run. First, a table of strata types with the cut-points is created. From which the look-up table for the *lut* approach and the `dat` dataset is created.

Unfortunately, the built-in check had to be switched off because the [onyambu's Rcpp approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72648486/3817004) returns results which deviate from the two other solutions.

[image]

To my surprise, the *lut* approach is faster than the *rcpp* approach for larger problem sizes in this benchmark set-up. *arau* is slower by 2 magnitudes.

#### Benchmark code

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
library(bench)

Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "std::vector<std::string> interval(std::vector<int> &x,
                                     std::vector<std::vector<int>> &y){
    std::vector<std::string> z;
    z.reserve(x.size());
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), std::back_inserter(z), 
      [&](int a, std::vector<int> b) {
        auto it = std::find_if(b.begin(), b.end(), [=](int w) {return a < w;});
        return it == b.end()? \"NA\":
              '[' + std::to_string(*(it-1)) + ',' + std::to_string(*it) + ')';
    });
    return z;
  }"
)

arau <- function(dat){
  dat[, tmp_id := .I]  # create a temporary identifier for each value row
  
  # NB: can remove the sort call if the strata are already ordered increasing
  dat_long = dat[, .(values, lb = sort(unlist(strata))), by = tmp_id]
  dat_long[, ub := shift(lb, -1), by = tmp_id]
  dat_long = dat_long[!is.na(ub)]
  
  dat_result = merge(
    dat, dat_long[lb <= values & values < ub, -'values'], by = 'tmp_id', all.x = T)
  dat_result[!is.na(lb) & !is.na(ub), cat := paste0('[', lb, ',', ub, ')')]
  dat_result[, .(values, strata_id, strata, cat)]
}

bm <- press(
  n_cat = c(3, 10),
  n_strata_id = c(4, 10),
  n_row = rev(10^(2:5)),
  {
    strata_dt <- data.table(strata_id = seq(n_strata_id))[
      , strata := .(.(strata_id + (10.0 * seq(n_cat + 1L)) )), 
      by = strata_id]
    # print(strata_dt)
    dat0 <- data.table(
      values = -as.double(rep(seq(n_row / n_strata_id), each = n_strata_id)),
      strata_id = rep(seq(n_strata_id), length.out = n_row)
      )
    dat0[strata_dt, on = .(strata_id), strata := i.strata]
    # print(dat0)
    lut <- strata_dt[, .(lo = head(strata[[1]], -1L), 
                         hi = tail(strata[[1]], -1L)), by = strata_id][
                           , cat := sprintf("[%i,%i)", lo, hi)]
    # print(lut)
    mark(
      lut = {
        dat <- copy(dat0)
        dat[lut, on = .(strata_id, values >= lo, values < hi), cat := i.cat][]
      },
      rcpp = {
        dat <- copy(dat0)
        dat[, cat:=interval(values, strata)][]
      },
      arau = {
        arau(copy(dat0))
      },
      check = FALSE,
      # check = function(x, y) {
      #   tmp <- all.equal(x, y, check.attributes = FALSE)
      #   if (!isTRUE(tmp)) {
      #     cat(tmp, "\n")
      #   }
      #   tmp
      # }
    )
  }
)
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

Comment: I did a bencmark with 400000 rows (only 4 unique) and your code is 40 times SLOWER than the Rcpp. It is Not correct to claim that it is faster without the bencmark results.

Comment: How do you read your graphs? My benchmark clearly shows that the Rcpp is fastest. Can you provide the times taken by each code

Comment: Also you are leaving the whole procedure of creating the lookup table. That is part of your solution. Not something done differently